SSL certificate fingerprint mismatch between OPNsense and browser
I've configured an OPNsense firewall's web GUI to use a self-signed certificate with the following SHA-256 fingerprint

However, when I open the web GUI from a web browser, it is showing a different SHA-256 fingerprint. I expected these to match.

I am sure that I've connected to the correct host and there are elements of the certificate that do match so why are the fingerprints different?

There is too much unknown here. We don't know your internal network structure and system setup, for example if there are middleboxes or antivirus which does SSL interception (many AV do). We don't know if you even look at the right information since basically everything relevant is not shown. This way one might do wild speculation only but not a real answer.

@SteffenUllrich The antivirus advice was absolutely spot on. Thank you for taking the time to leave this comment. I will accept it as the correct answer if you don't mind adding an answer. It turns out my antivirus ESET has SSL/TLS protection which can be turned off from the settings. When I temporarily turned it off, my web browser received a certificate with a matching fingerprint :)
